# transform: translateY(-50%) div elements loses quality

Tags: css

I'm designing a generator. Today, refactoring code I encountered a problem that I have seen several times in my path, but somehow I never penetrated into its existence. Namely - div after adding the attribute in CSS transform: translateY (-50%) loses on the quality of its elements inside, someone knows why this is happening? Elements are blurry, especially fonts and banners.

I'm using this line to center the diva vertically

[image: Low quality borders & text]

If i delete this line, everything back to normal

```
#message {
    width: 500px;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    position: fixed;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 201;
    padding: 20px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would believe that it is because og "half pixels".

You tell the div to transform -50%.
If the div has a height of 101px, the 50% will be 50.5px, and you cant have a half pixel.

You can check if this is the problem, by setting a specific height, that can be split in two, without going into halves.

Comment: You have right, #message has 481px height (50% * 1px)